# Horizontal and vertical alignment using hyperlinks in HTML

Tags: html, css, user-interface, hyperlink, scroll

I want to display 20 links as `Slide 1`, `Slide 2`, ..., `Slide 20` in an HTML page. I want `Slide 1` up to `Slide 10` one below another, and `Slide 11` to `Slide 20` one > below another, such that `Slide 1` is parallel to `Slide 11`, `Slide 2` with `Slide 12` etc.

```
Slide1     <->    Slide11
Slide2     <->    Slide12
Slide3     <->    Slide13
Slide4     <->    Slide14
Slide5     <->    Slide15
Slide6     <->    Slide16
```

and so on. I am using following code as of now but not able to figure out how to display `Slide 11`  to `Slide 20`.

```
<h4>
    <ul>
        <h4>
            <a href="FCT_Slide_Image1.1.html">Slide 1</a> 
        </h4>

        <h4>
            <a href="FCT_Slide_Image1.2.html">Slide 2</a>
        </h4>

        <h4>
            <a href="FCT_Slide_Image1.3.html">Slide 3</a>
        </h4>

        <h4>
            <a href="FCT_Slide_Image1.4.html">Slide 4</a>
        </h4>

        <h4>
            <a href="FCT_Slide_Image1.5.html">Slide 5</a>
        </h4>

        <h4>
            <a href="FCT_Slide_Image1.6.html">Slide 6</a>
        </h4>

        <h4>
            <a href="FCT_Slide_Image1.7.html">Slide 7</a>
        </h4>

        <h4>
            <a href="FCT_Slide_Image1.8.html">Slide 8</a>
        </h4>

        <h4>
            <a href="FCT_Slide_Image1.9.html">Slide 9</a>
        </h4>

        <h4>
            <a href="FCT_Slide_Image1.10.html">Slide 10</a>
        </h4>
```

Comment: where is the css you tried?

Comment: Hi, I am not using CSS for this. Is it possible only with CSS? I am new to CSS and HTML, please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, probably the easiest is to use a `<table>` if you are not considering CSS yet:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 1</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 11</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 2</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 12</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 3</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 13</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 4</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 14</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 5</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 15</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 6</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 16</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 7</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 17</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 8</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 18</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 9</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 19</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 10</a></td>
        <td><a href="#">Slide 20</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, inside each of the `<td>` tags you can put additional tags or give CSS style to modify the font size

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properly. You want to align these containers next to each other?
[image: Sample] [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhf3v/)

```
    <div id="Slide1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a>
        </li>
        <ul>
        </div>
<div id="Slide2">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a>
        </li>
        <ul>
</div>
<div id="Slide3">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a>
        </li>
        <ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
   #Slide1 {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: Orange;
    float: left;
}

#Slide2 {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: Yellow;
    float: left;
}

#Slide3 {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: Green;
    float: left;
}
```